# Arbitrary arrays as keys for another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need a data structure which will let me associate two `numpy` arrays with a `float`. This is really a 2-dimensional array, but I'd like to use arbitrary arrays as keys. For example:

```
    | a01 | a02 |
-----------------
a12 | 1.  | 3.  |
a11 | 2.  | 4.  |
```

where `axx` are `numpy` arrays with floats in them such as `array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.])`.

I tried using a `numpy` array as the data structure, but this doesn't work:

```
>>> a = np.array([1., 2.])
>>> b = np.array([3., 4.])
>>> c = np.array([])
>>> c[a][b] = 1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

I cannot use a python dictionary because `numpy` arrays aren't serialisable.

Any suggestions on how I could store this data?

Comment: Do all the arrays have the same size?

Comment: convert your `np.array` to `tuple` to be usable as `dict` keys

Comment: Along an axis they will be the same (so `a01` and `a02` will be the same, and `a11` and `a12` will be the same).

Comment: I was thinking of a [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy-spatial-kdtree) with `np.concatenate(a.flatten(), b.flatten())` as key, but indeed converting to tuples could be a better idea.